# Extracting values from a dataframe column with dtype 'o'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python Pandas. In my data frame there is a column called `'helpful'` which has a `dtype 'o'`. The values in the column are like `[2,5]`. I need to extract the 2 and the 5 in order to perform operations on them. Can anyone suggest how I can do that?

Comment: What is `print (type(df['helpful'].iat[0]))` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'helpful': {0: [2, 5], 1: [3, 6]}})
print(df)
Out[742]: 
  helpful
0  [2, 5]
1  [3, 6]

#access first row for column helpful
df.helpful.values[0]
Out[743]: [2, 5]

#access first element of first row for column helpful
df.helpful.values[0][0]
Out[744]: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'helpful': ['2,5','4,0','7,3']})

for val in df.helpful.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')):
    print val[0]
    print val[1]
    print '_'*3
```